# Battery Cycles being used very fast

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I am using a 13-inch mid 2014 MacBook Pro with Retina Display.
It is about 3 weeks old and already has clocked 13 charge cycles.

Is this too high ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using a 13-inch mid 2014 MacBook Pro with Retina Display. It is
>   about 3 weeks old and already has clocked 13 charge cycles. Is this
>   too high?

A charge cycle is just the process of using and then recharging the full capacity of the battery one time. [From Apple](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585):

> A charge cycle means using all of the battery’s power, but that
>   doesn’t necessarily mean a single charge. For instance, you could use
>   your notebook for an hour or more one day, using half its charge, and
>   then recharge it fully. If you did the same thing the next day, it
>   would count as one charge cycle, not two, so it may take several days
>   to complete a cycle.

You can't really have "too many" charge cycles unless there's something wrong with the battery and it's unable to hold a charge. That seems unlikely since your computer is brand new (and OS X will notify you if your battery condition is abnormal).

Furthermore, your particular model is rated for 1,000 charge cycles before it's considered "consumed" (meaning it'll no longer hold a reasonable charge and will likely need to be replaced). If your current rate of 13 charge cycles per three weeks holds, that means you're good for 4.5 years – in other words, nothing to worry about!

> Also, I follow the practice of fully charging it and then using till
>   about 40% before recharging without ever leaving it plugged in. Is
>   this the best practice to follow or should I leave it plugged in while
>   charging ?

Even if you leave your laptop plugged in at 100%, the system will actually silently discharge the battery to ~95% and back up to keep things moving. Apple used to recommend unplugging your laptop at least once a month, but their [current guidelines](http://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/#macbook) make no mention of that, so I wouldn't worry about it.